# How do I replace a column value, conditionally depending on another column value (with LEFT JOIN)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT * from #b as t
LEFT outer JOIN WR_16h_vs_MVA_16h_csv as csv
on t.PROBE_ID = csv.PROBE_ID;
```

which returns results that look like this:

```
|id|...|...|...|functionCC_A|...|functionCC_B|...|
------------------------------------------
|1 |   |   |   | lalala     |   | NULL     |   |
|2 |   |   |   | asdad      |   | bababa   |   |
|3 |   |   |   | NULL       |   | NULL     |   |
|n |   |   |   | werwer     |   | NULL     |   |
```

There are two `functionCC` columns because of a JOIN. I want a single `functionCC` column but here are the cases:

1. if `functionCC_A` is `NULL`, use value from `functionCC_B`
2. if`functionCC_A` has a value and so does `functionCC_B`, use
   `functionCC_B`
3. if `functionCC_A` has a value but `functionCC_B` is `NULL`, use `functionCC_A`
4. if both `NULL` leave as `NULL`

How can I craft my query so that I can replace the first `functionCC` (`functionCC_A`) column value conditionally, depending on the value in the second `functionCC` column (`functionCC_B`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null value from a list so something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(csv.functionCC,t.functionCC) AS functionCC 
from #b as t
LEFT outer JOIN WR_16h_vs_MVA_16h_csv as csv
on t.PROBE_ID = csv.PROBE_ID;
```

This satisfies all the criteria listed since you want 'b' if it's populated and `COALESCE()` will return `NULL` if none of the listed fields are populated.

I wasn't sure if the `_A` and `_B` were for illustration purposes, assumed one column named `functionCC` coming from each of the tables, so might have to adjust the names above.

Comment: Yes, for illustration purposes. To select all the other columns, too, must I explicitly specify them?

Comment: yeah if you want to do the same thing for multiple columns, you'll have to have a bunch of `COALESCE()` statements like above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and get back to you.

Comment: Fantastic, this worked great. Nice little trick there - thanks!